# Django Login with Ajax?

Tags: django, authentication

I'm working on a jquery function to post a login-form with ajax. In the ajax success: I want to handle the response differently if it's a successful login or not.

So in Django I wonder if i can build on the existing login-view to add some success/error variable to send back to the jquery function together with the returned page. I mean keep the view as it works by default but also add an extra "status" variable.

A small example of this would be great!

Answer (score 8):

your views.py

```
def logmein(request):
   username= request.GET.get('username')
   password = request.GET.get('pwd')
   stayloggedin = request.GET.get('stayloggedin')
   if stayloggedin == "true":
       pass
   else:
       request.session.set_expiry(0)
   user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
   if user is not None:
       if user.is_active:
           login(request, user)
           return HttpResponse('fine')
       else:
           return HttpResponse('inactive')
   else:
       return HttpResponse('bad')
```

your ajax

```
function logmein() {
    var username = $.trim($('#username').val());
    var pwd = $.trim($('#pwdlogin').val());
    var stayloggedin = document.getElementById('stayloggedin').checked;
    $.ajax({
        url : "/logmein/",
        type : "get",
        data : {
            username: username,
            pwd : pwd,
            stayloggedin : stayloggedin,
            next : next
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        if (data == "fine") {
            window.location = window.location;
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm already using djangos login view that will return a redirect to profile if the login is succesful or the form+errors if not. So i still want the default functionality there just add an extra "status" to the return so that jquery can put the failed form in the same div or the profile in another div.

Comment: why not ```type``` = ```post``` ? Any reason

Comment: No, don't do this. Don't pass login credentials through a GET request. GET requests should be only used for data retrieval. Sending sensitive data such as a user's login credentials like that... is less than ideal.

Answer (score 8):

You need to setup an jquery Ajax call to post to your Login view in django.

In the view you need to do something like this...

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

def login(request):                                                                                                                         
    if request.method == 'POST':                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        login_form = AuthenticationForm(request, request.POST)
        response_data = {}                                                                              
        if login_form.is_valid():                                                                                                           
            response_data['result'] = 'Success!'
            response_data['message'] = 'You"re logged in' 
        else:
            response_data['result'] = 'failed'
            response_data['message'] = 'You messed up'   

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

I have not tested this, but you're ajax call should look something like this.

```
<script> 
$.ajax({                                                                                                                           
    type:"POST",                                                                                                                    
    url: 'http://www.yousite.com/yourview/login/',                                                                                                   
    data: $('#login_form').serialize(),                                                                                  
    success: function(response){ 
        // do something with response
        response['result']; // equals 'Success or failed';
        response['message'] // equals 'you"re logged in or You messed up';                                                                                                     
     }                                                                                                                             
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Does this example extend the existing login view or do I have to make a new url that points to this new view? I'm already using django.contrib.auth.views.login for authentication. I need to keep the functionality. It returns a form with error (on failed login) or a profile on (sucess). I just want to put the results i different divs with jquery.

Comment: you can post directly to 'accounts/login/'

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but in case anyone else runs into this, here is what I did. Please note:

- I extended the default Django authentication system to use email address in place of the username. (My code should still work even if you use the default)
- I also used the Django Rest Framework status code (but again this is optional)
- You will need to set up the default Django registration templates as done here

In your views.py:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework import status

# Show the login page
def showLoginPage(request):
    return render(request,'registration/login.html',{})

# Actual login logic using AJAX
def login_request(request):
    
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
        context = {}
        email = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        
        account = authenticate(request,username=email, password=password)
        if account is None :
            context['message1'] = 'Invalid Login Details!'
            context['message2'] = 'Kindly Try Again With A Valid Email And Password'
            context['code']=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED            
            return JsonResponse(context, status = 200)
        
        elif account is not None and not account.is_active:
            context['message1'] = 'Sorry, your account is in-Active'
            context['message2'] = 'Kindly Check Your Email For Activation Link Or Contact Support'
            context['status'] = 'Error!'  
            context['code']=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED           
            return JsonResponse(context, status = 200)
        
        elif account :
              login(request, account)
              context['message'] = 'Successfully authenticated.'
              context['status'] = 'Success!'
              context['code']=status.HTTP_200_OK                                   
              return JsonResponse(context, status = 200) 

        else:           
            context['message'] = 'Invalid credentials'
            context['message2'] = 'Kindly Try Again With A Valid Email And Password'
            context['code']=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED           
            return JsonResponse(context, status = 200)

    return JsonResponse({}, status = 200)
```

urls.py:

```py
# default page = login page
path('', views.showLoginPage, name='login'),
# ajax login
path('post/ajax/loginUser', views.login_request, name='loginUser'),
# home page once logged in
path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
```

login.html:

```html
<!-- this div displays our response from the ajax post -->
<div id="login_error_div" style="display: none;" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show text-center" role="alert">
  <strong><span id="error1"></span></strong>
  <span id="error2"></span>
  <button id="hide_msg" type="button" class="close"  aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>

<!-- a hidden url to re-direct to the home page if successful -->
<input type="hidden" id="Urlhome" data-url="{% url 'home' %}" />

<script src="/static/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  (function() {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
      var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
      // Loop over them and prevent submission
      var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
          if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
          }else{
              sign_in_User()
          }                
          form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }, false);
      });
    }, false);
  })();
</script>

<script>
  const togglePassword = document.querySelector('#togglePassword');
  const password = document.querySelector('#id_password');
  togglePassword.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    // toggle the type attribute
    const type = password.getAttribute('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
    password.setAttribute('type', type);
    // toggle the eye slash icon
    this.classList.toggle('fa-lock-open');
  });
</script>    

<script>    
  $("#hide_msg").click(function (){    
    $("#login_error_div").hide()
  });
</script>

<script>
  function sign_in_user() {
    var url = $("#Urlhome").attr("data-url");
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();  
    var username = ($('#id_username')).val();
    var password = ($('#id_password')).val();  
    $.ajax({
      url: "{% url 'loginUser' %}",  
      type: "POST", // or "get"
      headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'}, // for csrf token
      data:{
        'username': username, 
        'password':password,
      },
      success: function loginResponse(response) {  
        if(response['code']=== 401){
          $('#login_error_div').show();
          $("#error1").text(response['message1']+' :')
          $("#error2").text(response['message2'])                      
        } else {
          location.href=url;
        }                                     
      }
    });   
  }    
</script>
```