# Django + Phonegap Authentication

Tags: python, ajax, django, phonegap, jsonresponse

I am building an application with Phonegap on the client side and a Django server on the backend. I am not able to authenticate the user. Here's my code.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.0.101/userbase/login/",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {"username": username,
               "account": account,
               "password": password,},

        success: function (json) {

            if (json.logged_in == true) {
                window.location.href = "products.html";
            }

            else {
                alert("Invalid Credentials. " + json.error);
            }

        }

    });
```

This is the AJAX call to log in the user from the `index.html`. It is authenticated temporarily as in the `views.py`

```
# SOME CODE

login(request, user=user)
print(request.user.is_authenticated())
response = JsonResponse(response_data)
response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type'

return response
```

prints `True`. But, when the window redirects to `products.html` and I make an AJAX request to my Django server and check if the user is authenticated or not, it returns False. I am not able to find the error.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried printing the json response to the browser? Can you include it in the post?

Comment: Refer here for a working example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929942/django-login-with-ajax

Comment: @pypypy Yes, I've tried printing the JsonResponse and it contains only the variables that I require. And that is not keeping the user logged in.

Comment: Are the appropriate session cookies being sent? Check in the Network tab of dev tools.

Comment: @pypypy No, they are not I think. It contains only two cookies `connect.sid` and `io`.

Comment: Without seeing it I'd suggest that's where your problem is. Default implementation uses a cookie named sessionid to validate auth sessions.

Comment: @pypypy Yeah, I realised that, can it be because the cookie is not being set on the browser. This error is occuring in Chrome too so I'm pretty sure that the cookie is not being set. The problem is, why?